# Unable to Access Microsoft Store on Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows VM on Azure. I want to install an App (Photos) from the Microsoft Store. However, Microsoft Store is not there on the VM. I tried installing it from the Microsoft Store website, but clicking "Get" is unresponsive.

I tried all the solutions given in: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-store-wont-open/ac3e7d57-e5b4-49f9-8a78-f5be9621797f but non of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the use of a Windows Server 2019 VM on which Microsoft Store is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

> To fix the Microsoft store issue in Windows 10/11, and make it work normally, please
> try with the below suggestions,

- **Try creating a new user account in windows**

*Windows Settings -> Accounts -> Add new account -> Click on _I don’t have this person’s sign-in information. -> Click on *Add a user without a Microsoft account* -> Add a new username & password.*

- **Try resetting windows store cache**

*Open Run (windows+R) -> Type *wsreset.exe* -> Enter -> Command executes -> Restart the PC*

- **Try running DISM command**

*Open command prompt as Admin
And type -
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
And Run the command and restart the PC.*

- **Try registering on the windows store again**

*Open PowerShell as Admin -> Type *Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}* -> Restart PC**

For more in detail, please refer: [Fix: Microsoft Store missing in Windows 10 (windowslatest.com)](https://www.windowslatest.com/2018/03/11/fix-microsoft-store-missing-in-windows-10/)

> **Microsoft Store gets Freezing while installing App(Photos), to resolve this issue please try with below suggestions,**

- Try temporarily disabling all security software
- Try troubleshooting in clean boot State
- Try running the system file checker
- Try fixing the Operating "*System 5*" errors.

For more in detail, please refer: [Microsoft Store apps keep crashing or freezing in Windows 11/10 (thewindowsclub.com)](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-random-windows-8-metro-app-crashes).